# How to read an array of characters using scanf(and without string functions)?

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to read and print array of characters using scanf. This is my source code. May I please know what is the error in this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
    int i;
    char str[20];
    printf( "Enter\n" );
    for ( i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++ )
        scanf( "%s", &str[i] );
    for ( i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++ )
        scanf( "%s\n", str[i] );
}
```

Comment: will you please tell us what error you are getting when you run this code?

Comment: A tip: your `char str[20]` is an array of `char`s, not strings

Comment: I would suggest you to read some basic C book.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I just shouldn't post that close to the weekend. I always screw it up on Fridays. ;-)

Comment: On running this code, compiler is printing "Enter"(this is my printf statement) an then the execution ends. It is not asking for any values to input.

Comment: @user3472728: Teacher's question. When execution reaches the `for` loop for the first time, what's the value of `str[i]`?

Answer (score 3):

You have *at least* three problems: The first is that `str` is a *single* string, not an array of strings, that would have been e.g.

```
char str[20][20];
```

The second problem is that you apparently try to print the "strings" with `scanf`.

The third problem is that you are using the array `str` as it was initialized. Local variables are *not* initialized, and they values are indeterminate. That means that the contents of `str` will seem to be random. Using uninitialized local variables, like you do in your first loop, leads to *undefined behavior*.

---

One way of fixing (parts) of the code could be like

```
char strings[20][20];

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    char *p = fgets(strings[i], sizeof(strings[i]), stdin);
    if (p == NULL)
        break;  /* Error reading, or "end of file" */

    /* The fgets function can leave the newline in the buffer, remove it */
    if (strings[i][strlen(strings[i]) - 1] == '\n')
        strings[i][strlen(strings[i]) - 1] = '\0';
}

for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    printf("String #%d: '%s'\n", i + 1, strings[i]);
```

Comment: how can I read an "array of char" using scanf in a similar way that we use for reading "array of numbers"? Can you please suggest modifications in my source code.

Comment: and the 4th problem is you haven't ordered that C programming book yet.

Comment: I want the source code without string functions i.e using basic functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    char str[20][32];
    printf("Enter\n");
    for (i=0; i < 20; ++i)
        scanf("%31s", str[i]);
    for (i=0; i < 20; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i, pos;
    char *str[20];
    char array[20*32];

    printf("Enter\n");
    for (pos=i=0; i < 20; ++i){
        int len;
        if(EOF!=scanf("%31s%n", &array[pos], &len)){
            str[i] = &array[pos];
            pos += len + 1;
        } else {
            str[i] = NULL;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i=0; i < 20 && str[i] != NULL; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    return 0;
}
```